# Разделение url'a

Tags: jquery, url

Есть картинки, при нажатии на них происходит вызов функции и дальнейшие действия. Я беру у них путь из атрибута `src` и заношу в переменную.

Содержимое переменных имеет вид:

```
/images/clients/2.jpg
/images/clients/14.jpg
```

Но мне нужно переделать их в такой вид:

```
/images/clients/2_full.jpg
/images/clients/14_full.jpg
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Обязательно использовать jQuery ?

Comment: Jquery-то тут при чем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'/images/clients/2.jpg'.replace('.jpg','_full.jpg')
```

[replace()](http://javascript.ru/String/replace)

Comment: Там куда ссылка, довольно размыто написано. Прочитал английский мануал и получилось)

 img_path = img_path.replace(".jpg","_full.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

Если очень просто, то так:

```
var getFullSrc = function (src){
    return src.replace(/(\d+)(\.je?pg)/i, '$1_full$2');
};

console.log( getFullSrc('/images/clients/2.jpg') );
```

Comment: Нет, если очень просто — то это у меня :-D

Comment: Тут можно поспорить: `'/images/clients/2.JPG'.replace('.jpg','_full.jpg')` или `2.jpeg` :]